# Left zero number has weird results

Tags: ruby, numbers, ruby-2.6

I was trying do some sum to numbers and have a number with a very left zero
and start to get wired results

`142 + 3 = 145`

but `0142 + 3 = 101`

What is the base number data type for ruby ? ( iam using repl 2.6.3 )

Comment: This is in the documentation: See https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in Ruby's "[Numbers](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers)" documentation:

> You can use a special prefix to write numbers in decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary formats. For decimal numbers use a prefix of `0d`, for hexadecimal numbers use a prefix of `0x`, for octal numbers use a prefix of `0` or `0o`, for binary numbers use a prefix of `0b`. The alphabetic component of the number is not case-sensitive.

Meditate on this:

```
0d170 # => 170
0D170 # => 170

0xaa # => 170
0xAa # => 170
0xAA # => 170
0Xaa # => 170
0XAa # => 170
0XaA # => 170

0252  # => 170
0o252 # => 170
0O252 # => 170

0b10101010 # => 170
0B10101010 # => 170
```

This is very common among programming languages.

If the concept of number bases is foreign, then these might help:

- "[Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)"
- [`Integer.to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-to_s)
- [`String#to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-to_i)